# Inheritance and eager loading

Tags: nhibernate

Given the following classes:

```
public class Parent
{
}

public class Child1 : Parent
{
    public Other other { get; set; }
}

public class Child2 : Parent
{
}

public class Other
{
}
```

Is there a way I can specify in a query of **Parents** that I want to eagerly fetch (i.e. join) the **Others** that are associated with **Child1** (the problem being that there are no **Others** at the level of **Parent**, which is the type that I'm querying)?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the Fetch strategy to "Join" to that column in the mapping for Child1.  In NHibernate xml config, add `fetch="join"` to your `set` node.  In Fluent NHibernate add `.Fetch.Join()` to the end of your call to "References" (something line `References(x => x.Other)`) in Child1Map.cs.

This may be what you were expecting `lazy="false"` or `.Not.LazyLoad()` to do, but turning off lazy loading doesn't do what you would expect.  See Ayende's post here for details: http://ayende.com/blog/4573/nhibernate-is-lazy-just-live-with-it

Comment: Thanks, but I specifically want to do this in the query, as I don't always want the eager fetching.  Often one can turn eager fetching on in the query where it doesn't exist in the mapping (although I understand that the reverse isn't supported), and that's what I'd like to do here.